# Find available grid position

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, c

I'm building a color box connecting game with objective-C and trying to figure out how to find the correct position when a block of boxes is placed incorrectly over another block of boxes.

See the attach image. In the image, you only need to move the left box one step to the right in order to connect the boxes and win.

However, if you place the left box on top of the other box (Image 2), I want to move it to the closest available free grid position.

This would be easy if the box was a simple square (a 1x1 grid, 2x2 grid, etc), but since the boxes can be complex, It's harder. There might also be a lot of boxes on the grid.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're new to heuristics like this, just take the KISS approach.

It couldn't be easier...

The user tries the object at x,y ok?

It does not "fit" there.

So, simply "spiral" outwards, trying it in other possible places.

Just keep trying until you find one where it fits.

```
234
915
876
```

so that's like "radius 1", you see?  then try "radius 2"

and so on.

It's that easy.   Just keep trying until you find one that "does work".

Work from the start position outwards, so that, you find the closest one.